# Save as PDF PHP page

Tags: php, pdf, tcpdf, dompdf

I have a PHP page, as you see on this page everybody can create schema for heating and cooling systems. I am at the end of my project, now I have a problem. I am trying to save as PDF my schema ( inside div). 
Firstly I tried to use TCPDF, unfortunately TCPDF does not support all CSS commands. Then I found DOMPDF, but it did not display PHP commands. Heere is a screenshot from my projects.[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use DOMPDF for this and DOMPDF also supports PHP Code.You can enable php on dompdf_config.inc.php file DOMPDF_ENABLE_PHP = true by default it false.

Comment: With 0.6.x dompdf no longer parses regular PHP code before rendering to PDF (inline script still works). So with that version you'll want to somehow parse the code first then feed the HTML output to dompdf.